# Dynamically change CORS -allowedOrigins - Play 2.4.x

Tags: playframework-2.0

I need to dynamically change the allowed origins for Play 2.4.x.

I have the below code but can't access "corsFilter.corsConfig.allowedOrigins".

I'm sure there must be an easy solution to customize Play CORS

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.http.HttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter) extends HttpFilters {
  def filters: Seq[CORSFilter] = {
    Seq(corsFilter)
  }
}
```

application.conf

```
play.http.filters = "Filters"
play.filters.cors {

  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins =  ["http://localhost", "http://localhost:8888", "http://localhost:9000"]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
  # The allowed HTTP headers. If null, all headers are allowed.
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Referer", "User-Agent", "access_token"]
  # The exposed headers
  exposedHeaders = ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Referer", "User-Agent", "access_token"]
  # Whether to support credentials
  supportsCredentials = false
  # The maximum amount of time the CORS meta data should be cached by the client
  preflightMaxAge = 1 hour
}
```